# bash script line by line

Tags: bash, file, logging

I'm looking for a bash script that read line by line one file .log

```
example .log file:

test1: AAAA
test2: BBBB
test3: AAAB
....
testx: BBBA
```

and print in stdout the results ( number of test, number of test type with different letters in the results (like AAAB or BAAA etc. )

```
example sdout:

Results with different letters, number of results with different letters
```

It's possibile? Thanks!

Comment: Yes very much possible, did you try anything?

Comment: I do not find any bash code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $2}' filename | sort | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
1 AAAA
1 AAAB
1 BBBA
1 BBBB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` loop to do so.

Created a test file.

```
$ cat test
test1: A
test2: B
test3: A
testx: B
```

Simple while loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    echo $i
done < test
```

Executing the script.

```
$ ./script.sh
test1: A
test2: B
test3: A
testx: B
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want only the results in sdout like (Total of test with results A,Total of test with results B ..)